# Can the effective transmission rate from a python script to an arduino be increased when using serial communication?

Tags: arduino, serial, servo

I attempting to move a servo (controlled by an Arduino) with a Python script. The Python script issues a command to the Arduino to tell it where to move the servo head to. The communication is handled via serial communication.

Python code:

```py
import serial
import time

port = 'COM3'  
baud_rate = 115200  

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud_rate)

def turnHead(direction):
    cmd = direction
    ser.write(cmd.encode('utf-8'))

while (True):
    rate = 1
    time.sleep(rate)
    turnHead("left")
    time.sleep(rate)
    turnHead("centre")
    time.sleep(rate)
    turnHead("right")
```

Arduino code:

```c
#include <Servo.h>

Servo head;

const int servoPin = 9;

String msg;

int x = 0;

void setup() {
  head.attach(servoPin);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("System initiated");

  head.write(180);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    msg = Serial.readString();

    if(msg == "left"){
      head.write(0);
    }
    else if(msg == "centre"){
      head.write(90);
    }
    else if(msg == "right"){
      head.write(180);
    }
    else{
      head.write(45);
    }
  }
}
```

If the `time.sleep()` function is removed from the script, the system stops working, i.e., the *RX* LED on the Arduino illuminates, showing that the Arduino is receiving the data, but the servo does not react. By adding a delay of 1 second or more, the system begins to behave as expected.

However, decreasing the delay to anything below 1 second breaks the system. Is there a reason for this or is this some sort of an error? Is there a way to decrease this time to something below 1 second as I hope to use this system for more advanced applications which will require a faster refresh rate.

Many thanks.

Comment: don't send a 6 character message, when only one character is sufficient

Comment: `Serial.readString()` wastes time waiting for data ... assemble the data in a buffer as it comes in ... do other tasks in between